# Como passar um valor diferente num formulário HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Estou criando um filtro de datas em HTML para que a consulta SQL possa retornar para mim um valor específico.

Só estou tentando dificuldades em passar essa informação porque o option do formulário precisa aparecer o mês como em `<option>Março</option>`.

Minha consulta SQL fica assim:

```
select codigo, id_usuario, codigo_usuario, data, hora, despesa, valor, modo, observacao, estabelecimento, genero, tipo from despesa where id_usuario = 1 and data between '2015-Março-01' and '2015-Março-31' ;
```

Eu gostaria de poder selecionar no formulário a opção Março e ele trocar esse mês pelo número 03, assim eu posso fazer um select certinho.

Eu só queria saber se existe uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso direto no formulário direto do HTML.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta você adicionar um value ao seu option. Veja:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#meses', function(){
  var mes = this.value;
  alert(mes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="meses">
  <option value="01">Janeiro</option>
  <option value="02">Fevereiro</option>
  <option value="03">Março</option>
  <option value="04">Abril</option>
  <option value="05">Maio</option>
  <option value="06">Junho</option>
  <option value="07">Julho</option>
  <option value="08">Agosto</option>
  <option value="09">Setembro</option>
  <option value="10">Outubro</option>
  <option value="11">Novembro</option>
  <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -3):

Atualmente é mais indicado usar o HTML5 DatePicker .
Ele vai te permitir selecionar a data e vai passar ela já formatada igual o servidor trabalha. No caso aí em particular você terá que tratar as datas, e tirar o mês, de 2015-Março-01 e serializar. O retorno começa em 0 não em 1. Então se vocÊ usa o datepicker você já vai poder selecionar a data e o mês direto no input, para enviar ou receber de seu request via sql .

Comment: Olá @David. Tente colocar código que suporte a sua resposta, nem que seja apenas um exemplo. Fica mais fácil de perceber.

Comment: Você está falando do [input type date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data)? Porque, se for, não são todos os navegadores que aceitam.

Comment: Amigo, está normatizado pela w3 . 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#date-time-and-number-formats
Stackoverfow em português é um lixo !